# GDAL show me a possible path error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, geospatial, spatial

I installed PostGIS on my Open SUSE distribution to make preparations for a project that should include a spatial database, so i heard to do that i need PostGIS libs for "spatial capabilities".

I wanna deploy an open source app that was done in django and I'm getting a:

```
OSError: libgdal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My current environment setup is:

- Linux OpenSUSE (last version)
- Python with django installed obviously
- PostGIS installed via .tar (last version)
- I have installed all requirements for PostGIS in their final versions
  (GEOS, Proj.4, GDAL, LibXML2)

I was looking for any help and i found this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#gdal

There sais, in Troubleshooting, if i have any problem similar to path errors i should specify them manually, i don't know how make it, in fact i don't know if my problem really is on my GDAL paths.

I thank in advance any orientation, and excuseme for my inexperience with django and spatial db's.

Comment: Did you run `ldconfig` as part of your installation procedure?

Comment: ... that is: after adding the /path/to/libdir to some file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/

Comment: `ldconfig` was a simple solution, thanks for your effective help. if i could give you the check as answer for this question, I would do :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must inform the dynamic loader that the new directory with .so libs exists and should be used.

- add the `/path/to/your/libdir/` to one of the textfiles in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` (the other postgres / postgis libs {postgres,geos,proj4} will probably already be there somewhere)
- run `ldconfig` (as root)
- (probably) restart postgres